# Is there a library for parsing/formatting TCP packets or anything that would help doing it?

Tags: c#, formatting, packet, sniffing

My application uses tcp to connect to my server and I am packet sniffing it to see how it works using wireshark, the first thing that crossed my mind is the packets that are coming to me in hex so manually looking and decoding is very hard.

So I tough was doing a parser where I do things like:

```
<packet id="0x01" name="undefined">
    <part name="userID" type="d"/>
</packet>
```

Where d is for decimal and would get 4 bytes to it.

My goal is to make something like this:
[image: packet parsed]

And below it a listview with the packet name as root and the part names inside with their value.

**I was looking around and found libraries to sniff the data etc but what I was really looking for is something that would help me parse/format it, is there any around ?**

Comment: what protocol are you trying to sniff?

Comment: @Yaur TCP like the title says if that matters nothing in particular it is just a c# app that TCP socket to a server in c#.

Comment: I don't mean what transport protocol, I mean what application level protocol.  This would be something like HTTP, RDP, etc.

Comment: @Yaur not really sure how to tell it I am not that much experienced in it and i really dont think that matter here in regards on how to format and parse it.... All I did was a basic client/server with auth in c# and want to sniff it for learning which I do using wireshark but the output is quiet complicated to understand just from looking and I would like to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the decoded packets, unfortunately from the perspective of TCP what you are looking at is already the decoded packet.
To get additional information you need a protocol dissector that operates on a higher level protocol.  For off the shelf protocols such a dissector probably already exists, but if you rolled your own protocol you will also need to roll your own dissector.  There is a [tutorial on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/custom_dissector.aspx) for building a custom dissector for wireshark which should help you get started if you want to go this route.